# Is this conversion the right approach for sending over TCP/IP?

Tags: c++, tcp

I want to send the Networkbyte over TCP/IP using
`int sendResult = send(sock, (char*)networkbyte, sizeof(userInput_converted), 0);`
Is this conversion the right approach or am I doing something wrong? Somehow than I send it the receiving end gets 0 insted of the number I input.

```
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

wchar_t buffer[1024];
int buffer_converted[1] = { 0 };

uint16_t networkbyte;
uint16_t hostbyte;

int convert(int input[]) {
    networkbyte = htons(input[1]);
    return 0;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Input a number\n";
    wcin >> buffer;
    buffer_converted[1] = { _wtoi(buffer) };
    convert(buffer_converted);
}
```

The following is my TCP/IP Client code. Maybe the problem is in here? I am still trying my hardest to get it to work without any warnings.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <WS2tcpip.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
#include "CSV-Writer.h"
#include <vector>
#pragma comment(lib, "ws2_32.lib")


using namespace std;

int TcpIpClient(int userInput)
{
    string ipAddress = "192.168.0.2";           // IP Address of the server
    int port = 2000;                        // Listening port # on the server

    // Initialize WinSock
    WSAData data;
    WORD ver = MAKEWORD(2, 2);
    int wsResult = WSAStartup(ver, &data);
    if (wsResult != 0)
    {
        //cerr << "Can't start Winsock, Err #" << wsResult << endl;
        return 10;
    }

    // Create socket
    SOCKET sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    if (sock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        //cerr << "Can't create socket, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        WSACleanup();
        return 11;
    }

    // Fill in a hint structure
    sockaddr_in hint;
    hint.sin_family = AF_INET;
    hint.sin_port = htons(port);
    inet_pton(AF_INET, ipAddress.c_str(), &hint.sin_addr);

    // Connect to server
    int connResult = connect(sock, (sockaddr*)&hint, sizeof(hint));
    if (connResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        //cerr << "Can't connect to server, Err #" << WSAGetLastError() << endl;
        closesocket(sock);
        WSACleanup();
        return 12;
    }

    // Do-while loop to send and receive data
    char buf[4096];
    bool active = true;
    bool a = false;

    do
    {
        // Prompt the user for some text
        //cout << "> ";
        //cin >> userInput[0];


        if (sizeof(userInput) > 0 && a == false)        // Make sure the user has typed in something
        {
            uint64_t userInput_converted;
            //for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(userInput); i++) {
            //  userInput_converted[i] = htonl(userInput[i]);
            //}
            userInput_converted = htons(userInput);
            int sendResult = send(sock, (char*)userInput_converted, sizeof(userInput_converted), 0);
            if (sendResult == SOCKET_ERROR)
            {
                //std::cout << "Socket Error!";
                return 13;
            }
            a = true;
        }
            // Wait for response
            ZeroMemory(buf, 4096);
            int bytesReceived = recv(sock, buf, 4096, 0);
            if (bytesReceived > 0)
            {
                short int* ibuf = (short int*)buf;
                std::vector<int> InputData;
                for (int i = 0; i < bytesReceived / 2; ++i, ++ibuf)
                {
                    short result = ntohs(*ibuf);
                    InputData.push_back(result);
                    //std::cout << result << std::endl;

                }
                if(CsvWriter(InputData)==0){
                }
                active = false;
            

        }

    } while (active == true);

    // Gracefully close down everything
    closesocket(sock);
    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `buffer_converted[1]` is out of bound...

Comment: `int buffer_converted[1];` why array? why not simply `int buffer_converted;`?

Comment: You have buffer overrun. Array indices are zero-based in C++ so it should be `buffer_converted[0]` (and `input[0]` correspondingly). That alone may cause any kind of problem but it may as well be somewhere in the code you didn’t show.

Comment: @Jarod42 maybe I am wrong but I only got htons to work with an array that’s why I put an array in the function definition and pass directly an array to the function, maybe I did something wrong and htons works also with int?

Comment: `uint16_t htons(uint16_t hostshort);`, no arrays here.

Comment: @numzero thanks I hate myself right now for that... I added the code for the tcp/ip client, I did not before because last time I was told to do a minimal reproducible example, thats why now some variabels are called diffrent "networkbyte" is in the tcp client "userInput_converted"

Comment: okay now i managed to brake everything, i get an socket error

Comment: I suppose you get Access Violation as there is `(char*)userInput_converted` instead of `(char*)&userInput_converted`. Before silencing the “conversion to pointer from an integer of different size” warning, you should’ve think twice should there be that conversion at all. And `userInput_converted` really should be 16-bit.

Comment: Oh, and also `sizeof(userInput) > 0` is always true (regardless of what is inside the sizeof actually).

Comment: @numzero sorry I thought removed all of the ```sizeof(userInput) > 0``` missed that one, what does that & do?  ```(char*)&userInput_converted```  while trying for the last hour or so I found out that something is not right with the conversion if I send deliberately this: ```char packet[2] = { 0x00,0x14};```  it works. Have to find out how to change an int into that format now, thought htons or htonl would do that.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_member_access#Built-in_address-of_operator